# Prove this relation for the legendre polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I'm asked to prove that$$P_{2n}(0)=(-1)^n\frac{1\cdot3\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}$$
given that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xu+u^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)u^n$$

I tried this:

Let $x=0$ and use $$(u^2+1)^{-1/2}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}  -1/2  \\ m   \end{pmatrix} u^{2m}$$ $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}  -1/2  \\ m   \end{pmatrix} u^{2m}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(0)u^n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already proved the relation. Your last line implies:
$$P_{2m}(0)=\binom{-1/2}{m}=\frac{(-1/2)(-3/2)\cdot \ldots\cdot(-(2m-1)/2)}{m!}=(-1)^m\frac{(2m-1)!!}{2^m\cdot m!},$$
as wanted.

As an alternative to the generating function technique, you can use the binomial theorem and the Rodrigues formula. Since:
$$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n\cdot n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$
we have:
$$ P_{2n}(0)=\frac{1}{4^n}[x^{2n}](x^2-1)^{2n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}.$$